# Swagger POST Json Body Parameter Schema YAML

Tags: json, post, yaml, swagger, swagger-editor

i'm working on a RESTful API using swagger-api and swagger-editor for routes.
I can't figure out why the JSON i am sending through body, never reaches my controller.
here is my YAML

```
  schemes:
  - http
  - https

produces: [application/json, multipart/form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded]

paths:
 /projects:
    x-swagger-router-controller: project
    post:
      description: create a new project
      operationId: postProjects
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: param1
          in: body
          description: description
          required: false
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Project" 
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Project" 
        default:
          description: Error
          schema: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"

definitions:
  Project:
    properties:
      name:
       type: string
    required:
      - name
```

an example of the post request i'm sending.

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"test"}' http://127.0.0.1:10010/projects
```

and the response

```
{"message":"Request validation failed: Parameter (param1) failed schema validation","code":"SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED","failedValidation":true,"results":{"errors":[{"code":"OBJECT_MISSING_REQUIRED_PROPERTY","message":"Missing required property: name","path":[]}],"warnings":[]},"path":["paths","/projects","post","parameters","0"],"paramName":"param1"}
```

If i set the parameter "name" as not required, i just received an empty response like this
    { param1: 
       { path: [ 'paths', '/projects', 'post', 'parameters', '0' ],
         schema: 
          { name: 'param1',
            in: 'body',
            description: 'description',
            required: false,
            schema: [Object] },
         originalValue: {},
         value: {} } }
I have no clue why since other format such as header, path or formdata works fine.
I always receive an empty object. `req.swagger.params` has no value.
I tried several schema but even the simplest is not working.
i can tell from the header that 'content-type': 'application/json'.
So the content type is set, the schema validates a simple string argument named "name". Everything should be ok. but still not.

Comment: It might be completely unrelated but for me I had to downgrade the `swagger-express-mw` node package back to `0.1.0` to temporarily resolve this issue.

Comment: I did downgrade the package but for other reasons and still the same..
I opened an issue on github.

Comment: can you post the link to the github issue?

Comment: you can find the opened issue  [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/526)  but i'm afraid the answer is not very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed.
It wasn't swagger related.
I built an API with nodeJs and i realized i didn't have a middleware to handle body parameter. 
So because i missed a step before enabled the swagger middleware, i couldn't do anything with body parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind getting null values when sending json data to the API backend is the paramater path most of the time you give and the naming you give the parameter.

You also have to declare explicitly the type of schema you expect

You have to set parameter name to `body` and set `in: body` so that it picks the body object as a JSON

An example is here. You can try it out

```
/auth/register:
    post:
      tags:
        - Auth
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: user
          description: Create a new user.
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - firstName
              - lastName
              - email
              - password
              - confirmPassword
            properties:
              firstName:
                type: string
              lastName:
                type: string
              email:
                type: string
              password:
                type: string
              confirmPassword:
                type: string
            example:
              firstName: Jane
              lastName: Doe
              email: janedoe@gmail.com
              password: pass
              confirmPassword: pass
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
```